# ¿Cómo generar sentencias sql para miles de registros en python?

Tags: python, sql

Buen día. Estoy tratando de generar un pequeño script que me permita generar sentencias sql (por el momento delete) que me permita borrar datos de manera masiva para una base de datos SQL Server.

Hasta ahora no he podido lograrlo debido a que me aparece el siguiente error:

```html
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 3' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Obtener columnas llaves: En este caso únicamente tengo una.
   `array_column_keys = ['id']`. Pero podría darse el caso de que tenga dos o más.
2. Obtener registros de la columna y guardarlos en un arreglo. En este caso tengo más de 6K registros, algo así:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ... ,6925, 6926, 6927, 6928]
```

3. Con el siguiente código genero arreglos de un tamaño máximo de 100 que se guardan dentro del arreglo principal "tupla". En el siguiente ejemplo me quedarían 70 arreglos.

```
no_keys = 100
tupla = [tupla[i:i + no_keys] for i in range(0, len(tupla), no_keys)]
```

Ya teniendo todo esto, intento generar una consulta SQL que elimine los registros de cada una de los 70 arreglos (con un tamaño máximo de 100):

```
arr_queries = []
for sub_arr_keys in array_keys:
    str_column_keys = " || ".join(array_column_keys)
    str_query = (f"DELETE FROM {rds_table_name} WHERE {str_column_keys} "f"in {sub_arr_keys}") 
    arr_queries.append(str_query)
```

lo que me genera algo como:

```
['DELETE FROM dbo.prueba WHERE id in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]', 'DELETE FROM dbo.prueba WHERE id in [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]' ... ]
```

El problema es cuando quiero escribir en la base de datos. Para esto utilizo una conexión JDBC con PYODBC.

```
try:
    conn = SQLServerUtils.get_connection("secret_name")
    for i in range(0 ,len(arr_queries)):
        print(f"Queries count: {i+1} / {len(arr_queries)}")
        SQLServerUtils.execute_query(conn, arr_queries[i], "sns_arn_name", True, True)
    print(f"|{dt.now()}| QUERY EXECUTION FINISHED")
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Me regresa muchas veces lo siguiente:

```
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with '0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a resolver este problema, ya que según el error el máximo permitido es 128, pero yo solo le paso 100 (o 50) valores por query, en total ejecutaría 70 (o 139 si tomamos un tamaño de 50). Lo que según yo podría correr sin problemas pero no lo hace.

Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: ¿Es correcta la sintaxis? A `IN` le debería seguir un paréntesis...

Comment: No olvides además agregar en las etiquetas que estás haciendo referencia a SQL Server. SQL hace referencia al lenguaje SQL como tal, SQL Server es el SGBD (DBMS).

Comment: Otro tema: tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Buscá la manera de hacer una consulta parametrizada en lugar de _concatenar y ya_ tus variables.

Comment: No @padaleiana, efectivamente no es correcta la sintaxis, de ahí que el error menciona `The identifier that starts with`, esta considerando lo que está entre corchetes como un nombre, y claro como nombre de variable,  es demasiado largo.